# Django Admin 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied IIS

Tags: python, django, http-status-code-403

first of all I apologize for my bad English.

Did I upload the Django project to the windows server, but when I added data from the admin panel, the result I got is as follows.

**"403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.
You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied."**

Settings.py

```
from pathlib import Path
import os

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent




DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    "home",
    'django.contrib.sitemaps'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    
    'htmlmin.middleware.HtmlMinifyMiddleware',
    'htmlmin.middleware.MarkRequestMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'umy.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'umy.wsgi.application'



DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


LANGUAGE_CODE = 'tr'

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Istanbul'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

#STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedStaticFilesStorage'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
  
    <handlers>
      <add name="Python FastGCI" path="*" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="c:\python39\python.exe|c:\python39\lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" />
    </handlers>
        <httpErrors errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly" />
  </system.webServer>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="umy.wsgi.application" />
    <add key="DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE" value="umy.settings" />
    <add key="PYTHONPATH" value="C:\Inetpub\vhosts\domain.com\httpdocs" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

it records to the database, but this is the error I get on the return path

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you have already resolved the issue. I had the same issue and added a new site start from scratch following steps in here https://github.com/az-09/deploy-api-app-iis. Then it worked. Please let me know how it goes.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29894655)

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the appropriate permissions to the IIS user for accessing your directory in question, this can be done by changing the properties-> permissions of the directory.
[image]

Add two users in this:
1.iis_iusrs
2.iusr
Make sure to give the acess as per your requirements